# How to write an event + eventhandler? C#

Tags: c#

Hey guys I want to have an event that would be called "OnMonsterKilled" this should trigger when a monster die so hp = 0.
Could you give me some good help? maybe with some explanation I'm not the best atm in those things.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, one important thing to know about are delegates. Delegate instances are strongly typed method references.

You define a delegate type like this:

```
public delegate string IntToString(int i);
```

Now, you can declare a delegate variable like this:

```
IntToString myDelegate;
```

And you can assign it a method that has the right signature.

```
string ConvertInt(int i)
{
    return i.ToString();
}

...

IntToString myDelegate;
myDelegate = ConvertInt; // Without the parentheses!
string s = myDelegate(5); // "5"
```

Delegates are mulicast, i.e. they can hold a reference to multiple methods. When the delegate is called, all these methods are then executed in order

Given this other method:

```
string ConvertDecorated(int i)
{
    return "**" + i.ToString() + "**";
}
```

You can add a second delegate:

```
myDelegate += ConvertDecorated;
myDelegate(5); // "**5**"
```

If the delegate has a return type (i.e. is not void), then the result of the last method called will be returned.

You can also remove a method:

```
myDelegate -= ConvertDecorated;
myDelegate(5); // "5" result of first method.
```

---

Ok, now to events. An event is a wrapper around a delegate variable. A little bit like a property is a wrapper around a field. Moreover, an event does not allow you to assign a new method to the event with equal (=) and thus remove all the other method references. You can only use `+=` and `-=`. It also adds a very basic thread safety to the "pure" delegates.

You declare an event by specifying a delegate type:

```
public delegate void MonsterKilledEventHandler(object Source, MonsterInfo mi);
public event MonsterKilledEventHandler MonsterKilled;
```

Now you can rise the event like this, first making sure that it is not null:

```
private void OnMonsterKilled(MonsterInfo mi)
{
    MonsterKilledEventHandler eh = MonsterKilled; 
    if(eh != null) {
        eh(this, mi);
    }
}
```

It is important to first assign it to a temp variable if you want to ensure thread safety. This works, because delegates a immutable. I.e. If you add a method with += then a fully new delegate is created with a new method list and assigned to the variable. Event if the delegate was changed by another thread after assigning it to `eh`, eh would preserve its original value.

Starting with C# 6.0 you would simply write

```
private void OnMonsterKilled(MonsterInfo mi)
{
    MonsterKilled?.Invoke(this, mi);
}
```

Now someone wanting to subscribe to the event just writes

```
// monsterManager is an instance of the class defining the event
monsterManager.MonsterKilled += MyMonsterKillledHandler;

...

private void MyMonsterKillledHandler(object Source, MonsterInfo mi)
{
    // Be happy, the world just got better.
}
```

---

Note also that you can easily create a delegate on the fly with lambda expressions:

```
monsterManager.MonsterKilled += (s, mi) => {
    Celebrate("Monster " + mi.Name + " was killed!");
};
```

---

See:
- [Handling and Raising Events](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/edzehd2t(v=vs.110).aspx) (msdn)
- [Delegates and Events](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter2/Events.aspx) (C# in Depth by Jon Skeet)
- [C# Event Implementation Fundamentals, Best Practices and Conventions](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20550/C-Event-Implementation-Fundamentals-Best-Practices) (on CodeProject by 
Jeffrey Schaefer)